# R: Masked Functions

Tags: r

In the stats package, there is a highly useful function called reorder(). 
In the gdata package, there is also a function called reorder().

How do I force reorder() from stats, not to be overwritten when loading the gdata package? Or, is there a way to reference which reorder() you want to use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `stats::reorder()` to reference the version in stats.

Comment: Interesting that Nico's answer, was upvoted more considering that you answered the same thing at nearly the same time. I guess rep attracts votes. Thanks!

Comment: And so do checks, it seems.  Thanks!

Comment: So just now (presumably one person, though it could have been chance) just went through and upvoted a couple of my old answers that were at 9 up to 10.  Whoever you are, if you ever see this message, thanks for the badges!

Comment: @Aaron, the badges were just a bonus. You were so close to 10k...

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true too, though I didn't think of that at the time.  Thanks again, @GSee!

Answer (score 17):

From the Examples section of `?library`:

```
 ## if you want to mask as little as possible, use
 library(mypkg, pos = "package:base")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `stats::reorder()`